# XPath contains to target specific type of link path

Tags: xpath

I am having a lot of difficulty constructing an XPath query to return the kinds of URL's that I need. The XPath query below works for most cases however, I have been trying to tweak it so it only returns the URL where the actual page name contains 'about' and not the URL's where `about` is found in the directory name.

Current output (Bad):

```
https://www.domain.com/about/account.asp
```

Desired Output:

```
https://www.domain.com/about/about.asp
```

XPath

```
 (//a[contains(@href,'about')]/@href)[1]
```

**NOTE:** Because I am using a PHP XPath engine I can only utilize an XPath 1.0 solution.

I appreciate any suggestions!

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

XPath 1.0's string manipulation capabilities are very limited, you can only do this based on some assumptions.

Eg., if all URLs end with `.asp`, search for something like `/about.asp`, or a more general `/about.`. A very dirty hack would be to cut off everything starting at the first `?`, only use the last few characters (to allow suffixes of different length like `.xhtml` or `.pl`) and search in there:

```
[
  contains(
    substring(substring-before(., '?'), string-length(substring-before(., '?')) - 10),
   'about'
  ) or (
    not(contains(., '?')) and
    contains(substring(., string-length(.) - 10), 'about')
  )
]
```

And this still should still be extended for hashes `#` in place of `?` to fetch most cases, but there still will be enough it will fail at.

I would highly recommend to use some regular expression from PHP which will be much more robust and convenient. Or use an external XPath 2.0/XQuery processor like Saxon, BaseX, ...

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution:

```
//a[contains(@href, '/about.asp')]
```

But assuming you don't want to do that, I don't think it's possible to do what you need. The closest I got:

```
//a[contains(@href, 'about') and not(contains(substring-after(@href, 'about'), '/'))]
```

Explanation: *"Select any `<a>` element that, in its `@href` attribute, does contain `'about'` and does not contain any `'/'` after `'about'`."*

The problem is, that while it matches `https://www.domain.com/account/about.asp` and it (correctly) does not match `https://www.domain.com/about/account.asp`, it also does *not* match `https://www.domain.com/about/about.asp`, because there's an `"about"` substring succeeded by a `'/'`.

The best you can do, I think, is to simply select `//a[contains(@href, 'about')]` and then use your PHP to filter the results as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you remember which browser you used? Internet Explorer counts element nodes beginning by 0.

about.asp obviously comes before account.asp, so I would use this :

```
(//a[contains(@href,'about')]/@href)[0]
```